# How to decode this javascript?

Tags: javascript

My question is how can I decode this JavaScript and how is encoded (with which program or online tool).

Here is the JavaScript that I want to decode:
http://pastebin.com/hZvKySjj

Comment: If you don't have an idea about what it _should_ do, deobfuscating it will be nearly impossible.

Comment: This isn't something that can be decoded easily, this is just complex code writing.

Comment: It's not encoded. It is fairly obfuscated though. Any idea what it should do ?

Comment: A general starting point: http://jsbeautifier.org/

Comment: Where did this script come from?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Every obfuscated script needs some kind of `eval`. In here, the lines

```
_L = 'constr\x75\x63\x74\x6F\x72';
[][_L][_L](_Z[_h._t4](_F))();
```

are doing this. `_L` is the string `"constructor"`, and `[].constructor.constructor`  is the `Function` constructor. It will be called with the decoded script, and the resulting function will be called. We can substitute it with an `alert`, paste the script in the console*, and wait for the result - we don't even need to understand how the decoding works. In your case, the result is (yes, including all the comments and linebreaks):

```
var alarm ="0";
var content = document;

if ((content.getElementById("wrapper") != null))
{
    document.getElementById('wrapper').style.display = 'block';
}

function a ()
{
    if ((content.getElementById("links") != null))
    {
        var temp = content.getElementById("links").innerHTML;
        if ((temp.indexOf('nofollow')+1) > 0)  alarm = "1";
        else if ((temp.indexOf('noindex')+1) > 0)  alarm = "1";
    }
    else alarm = "1";
}

function b ()
{
    if ((content.getElementById("aa") != null) && (content.getElementById("ab") != null))
    {
        temp = document.getElementById("aa").href;
        if ("http://uc-portaller.ru/" != temp) alarm = "1";

        temp = document.getElementById("ab").innerHTML;
        if ("скрипты для ucoz" != temp) alarm = "1";
    }
    else alarm = "1";
}

function c ()
{
    if ((content.getElementById("ba") != null) && (content.getElementById("bb") != null))
    {

        temp = content.getElementById("ba").href;
        if ("http://austere.ru/" != temp) alarm = "1";

        temp = content.getElementById("bb").innerHTML;
        if ("доска объявлений" != temp) alarm = "1";
    }
    else alarm = "1";
}

function d ()
{
    if ((content.getElementById("ca") != null) && (content.getElementById("cb") != null))
    {

        temp = content.getElementById("ca").href;
        if ("http://www.for-creative.com/" != temp) alarm = "1";

        temp = content.getElementById("cb").innerHTML;
        if ("темы для ucoz" != temp) alarm = "1";
    }
    else alarm = "1";
}

a ();

if (alarm == "0") b ();
if (alarm == "0") c ();
if (alarm == "0") d ();

if (alarm == "1") prompt('Нарушены условия использования, по всем вопросам обращайтесь в ICQ:', '376880395');












$(document).ready(function(){

    //When you click on a link with class of poplight and the href starts with a # 
    $('a.poplight[href^=#]').click(function() {
        var popID = $(this).attr('rel'); //Get Popup Name
        var popURL = $(this).attr('href'); //Get Popup href to define size

        //Pull Query & Variables from href URL
        var query= popURL.split('?');
        var dim= query[1].split('&');
        var popWidth = dim[0].split('=')[1]; //Gets the first query string value

        //Fade in the Popup and add close button
        $('#' + popID).fadeIn().css({ 'width': Number( popWidth ) }).prepend('');

        //Define margin for center alignment (vertical + horizontal) - we add 80 to the height/width to accomodate for the padding + border width defined in the css
        var popMargTop = ($('#' + popID).height() + 80) / 2;
        var popMargLeft = ($('#' + popID).width() + 80) / 2;

        //Apply Margin to Popup
        $('#' + popID).css({ 
            'margin-top' : -popMargTop,
            'margin-left' : -popMargLeft
        });

        //Fade in Background
        $('body').append('<div id="fade"></div>'); //Add the fade layer to bottom of the body tag.
        $('#fade').css({'filter' : 'alpha(opacity=0)'}).fadeIn(); //Fade in the fade layer 

        return false;
    });


    //Close Popups and Fade Layer
    $('a.close, #fade').live('click', function() { //When clicking on the close or fade layer...
        $('#fade , .popup_block').fadeOut(function() {
            $('#fade, a.close').remove();  
    }); //fade them both out

        return false;
    });


});




        $.fn.tabs = function () {
            return this.each(function () {
               var $tabwrapper = $(this); 

               var $panels = $tabwrapper.find('> div');
               var $tabs = $tabwrapper.find('> ul a');

               $tabs.click(function () {  
                   $tabs.removeClass('selected');
                   $(this).addClass('selected');

                   $panels
                    .hide() // hide ALL the panels
                    .filter(this.hash) // filter down to 'this.hash'
                        .show(); // show only this one

                   return false;
               }).filter(window.location.hash ? '[hash=' + window.location.hash + ']' : ':first').click();
            });
        };

        $(document).ready(function () {
            // console.log(window.location.hash);

            $('div.tabs').tabs();
        });
```

<sub>*) Of course you need to be sure what you're doing. There's always a small risk that it's a malicious script, and you might have not found all `eval`s. @jfriend00's tip on executing the decoding snippets line-by-line is a safer way.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

The only way I know of to understand what this code does is to find a safe environment (in case the code has malicious intent) and execute it line-by-line in a debugger and watch what it does as it deobfuscates itself to turn itself into normal javascript.  The variable names will often stay obscured, but the giant string in _O will get decoded into something (probably javascript code).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at: http://www.labnol.org/software/deobfuscate-javascript/19815/

They show you how can you do something like that, it's basically a matter of using chrome debugger to "beautify" the code and make it easier to read.

Some versions of chrome don't have the command on a context menu, just look for the command "Pretty print" (has a icon like -> **{}**)

Once done that, you can use a javascript console to evaluate small snippets of code to reverse engineer it. Eg. the expression (at the beginning of your code)

```
1) (s\u0065lf + ([] * 0) * 1)
2) '\x5B'
3) ((s\u0065lf + ([] * 0) * 1)[0 ^ 0] == '\x5B')
```

returns this string on my browser

```
1) "[object Window]0"
2) "["
3) true
```

Just find the starting point and follow from there. Obfuscated code follows the same rules as normal one, it's just all messed up.

Comment: You didn't really look at the pastebin code, did you? The code *is* already beatified/pretty printed.

Comment: I think I paid too much attention to the blue middle part that did'n notice that.